# CATREG on SPSS is it possible to write an equation for CATREG on SPSS

Tags: regression, data-analysis, regression-analysis

From this output would it be possible to write an equation like with multiple linear regression?

So:

$$\text{Salary} =0.032\cdot \text{Gender} + 0.013\cdot \text{Ethnicity} + 0.097\cdot \text{Subject}$$
Or is it this not the right way to do so?

I have done extensive research and cannot find any examples similar to this.

Thanks in advance :)

[image]

Comment: Are the tags that i put appropriate. Had no tag options for CATREG, SPSS, available

Comment: They are OK, except for the logistic-regression (removed). SPSS etc is way too much statistical specification for mathematics forum...

Answer (score 0):

It is OK as long as you remember that this model is with respect to a standardized data, which in your case is standardized salary $y$.

(i.e., $y$ is not salary per-se, but $y = (\text{salary}-\text{mean(salary)})/\text{SD(salary)}$).

Comment: Thanks so much Vancak.

Comment: Thats very helpful  :)

Comment: You're welcome, and you can except the answer if it satisfies you/ answers the question.